# Clojure 1.9 windows install

Tags: clojure

In the past I've use the windows installer provided at clojure.org to install clojure on my various Windows machines. Clojure 1.9 has been out for a few weeks now but still no sign of an installer for Windows or a generic Java-based install, as far as I can find.

I've tried downloading the jars from clojure.org and running

```
java -jar clojure.1.9.0.jar
```

but that just dumps stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2204)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2213)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2232)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:450)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:426)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6548.invoke(core.clj:6046)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6045)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6029)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5848)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5843)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6493.invoke(core.clj:5888)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5887)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5868)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5925)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5909)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
        at clojure.core.server$loading__6434__auto____8456.invoke(server.clj:9)
        at clojure.core.server__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.core.server__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2204)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2213)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2232)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:450)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:426)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6548.invoke(core.clj:6046)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6045)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6029)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5848)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5843)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6493.invoke(core.clj:5888)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5887)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5868)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5925)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5909)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5947)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:381)
        at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:487)
        at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:336)
        at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class or clojure/spec/alpha.clj on classpath.
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:426)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6548.invoke(core.clj:6046)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6045)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6029)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5848)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5843)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6493.invoke(core.clj:5888)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5887)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5868)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5925)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5909)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:659)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
        at clojure.main$loading__6434__auto____8543.invoke(main.clj:11)
        at clojure.main__init.load(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.main__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 55 more
```

and as I don't have files `clojure/spec/alpha__init.class` or `clojure/spec/alpha.clj` it appears that at the moment I'm out of luck.

So - is there a step-by-step to go from having the 1.9.0 jars to making it all run on Windows?

All suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR:

You also have to download [org.clojure/spec.alpha](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/spec.alpha) and [org.clojure/core.specs.alpha](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/core.specs.alpha).  Then start with:

```
java -cp clojure-1.9.0-alpha17.jar;spec.alpha-0.1.123.jar;core.specs.alpha-0.1.10.jar clojure.main
```

(Note, that your versions there will be different; and there will be `:` instad of `;` for the unix family of OS).

## How to find out about and fetch the other deps

With the recent change in Clojure to use dedicated artifacts for Spec in an alpha sub-namespace, it is no longer easy to start a simple REPL just with the regular jar (e.g. `java -jar $CLOJURE_JAR clojure.main`). So how to start it now?

As of before you are better off to do a `lein new` somewhere, change the *org.clojure/clojure* dependency to the version you like and do a `lein deps :tree` to fetch all that is needed and display what things *org.clojure/core* now depends on. E.g.

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0-alpha17"]
   [org.clojure/core.specs.alpha "0.1.10" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure] [org.clojure/spec.alpha]]]
   [org.clojure/spec.alpha "0.1.123" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

All your artifacts end up in `~/.m2/repository`. So next you have to build up your classpath to call the REPL. You can now run `lein with-profile uberjar cp` in that dummy project to get the class path Leiningen is using.  E.g.:

```
$ lein with-profile uberjar cp
/tmp/xxx/test:/tmp/xxx/src:/tmp/xxx/resources:/tmp/xxx/target/classes:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0/clojure-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/spec.alpha/0.1.143/spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.specs.alpha/0.1.24/core.specs.alpha-0.1.24.jar
# this will be `;` instead of `:` as well here for windows
```

Remove the *test*, *src*, and *resources* ones and that is, what you have to pass to `-cp`.

## Future solution

As stated in the [Getting Started](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started) the `clojure` CLI is not yet available for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The only change required to run on Windows is to use `;` as the class path separator instead of `:` like so:



`java -cp clojure-1.9.0.jar;spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar;core.specs.alpha-0.1.24.jar clojure.main`

Comment: @JBiserkov thanks for the hint.  i'll update the answer.