# Running Clojure 1.9.0 on Windows redux

Tags: clojure

Last month I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948549/clojure-1-9-windows-install) about how to get the latest version of Clojure to run on Windows. @cfrick was kind enough to provide some guidance, but after following his suggestion and monkeying with it for a while now I'm still unable to get Clojure 1.9.0 to run on Windows. I know I must be doing something stupid, but here's what I've got:

I downloaded all the 1.9.0 jars from clojure.org and put them in a directory, along with the core.specs.alpha and spec.alpha jars:

```
01/12/2018  10:34 PM    <DIR>          .
01/12/2018  10:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/14/2017  05:55 PM         3,688,794 clojure-1.9.0.jar
12/14/2017  05:55 PM         2,816,528 clojure-1.9.0-javadoc.jar
12/14/2017  05:55 PM         1,052,237 clojure-1.9.0-slim.jar
12/14/2017  05:55 PM           606,466 clojure-1.9.0-sources.jar
01/12/2018  03:43 PM             4,236 core.specs.alpha-0.1.24.jar
01/12/2018  03:42 PM           591,287 spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar
```

I then tried the command line @cfrick suggested, substituting in the up-to-date version numbers of the specs.alpha and core.specs.alpha jars:

```
java -cp clojure-1.9.0.jar:spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar:core.specs.alpha-0.1.24.jar clojure.main
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
```

That's all that it dumps, so at least that's an improvement over the long list of errors it threw when it couldn't find core.specs.alpha and spec.alpha. :-)

So I dug out the `jar` utility, dumped the contents of `clojure-1.9.0.jar` into a file, and found that the class `clojure/main.class` exists in the jar. I tried re-running the java command above specifying the class name as `clojure/main` instead of `clojure.main` but got exactly the same error, so I guess there's no difference between `.` and `/` in the class name.

Just for fun (?) I tried running it using clojure-1.9.0-slim.jar but got the same error. I also tried surrounding the specified class path in double quotes, just to try something else, but got the same results. I also tried fully-qualifying the names of the .jar files with the directory in which they reside, appropriately double-quoted - still, same error.

I'd appreciate further guidance on how to get Clojure 1.9.0 to run from the command line, without using something like Leiningen or Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `:` use `;` as the class path separator:

`java -cp clojure-1.9.0.jar;spec.alpha-0.1.143.jar;core.specs.alpha-0.1.24.jar clojure.main`

Comment: Many thanks! I *knew* it had to be something simple I just couldn't see. I see you also updated the other question with this information. Well done!

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems you can "pour" the contents of the spec.alpha and core.specs.alpha jars in the main one (just don't overwrite the META-INF\MANIFEST.MF) to get a single clojure.jar and start a repl via `java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main` like in the pre 1.9 days. This does defeat the whole purpose of splitting spec from the main jar, but solves cross-platform issues like `:` vs `;`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to install Boot or Lein, really you're not going to get far without those.