# Exception running clojure-1.9.0.jar: missing clojure/spec/alpha__init.class and clojure/spec/alpha.clj

Tags: java, clojure

Leiningen downloaded `clojure-1.9.0.jar` as a dependency.   It's located at `~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0`.   It works fine through a lein repl.

However, if (from `~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure` I run `java -jar 1.9.0/clojure-1.9.0.jar`, instead of the expected behaviour (initiation of a REPL) I get an exception:

`Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class or clojure/spec/alpha.clj on classpath.`

For other Clojure versions (1.8.0, 1.6.0, 1.4.0) I get a REPL as expected.

So what's wrong with clojure-1.9.0.jar - - or my setup - or my understanding?

Note:
If I run `lein repl` in a directory containing a project with a Clojure 1.9.0 dependency I get a REPL with Clojure 1.9.0, but if I start Leiningen from any other directory I get a REPL with Clojure 1.8.0.  In both cases, REPL versions are `REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12`.
Running `lein upgrade` results in the message `Leiningen is already up-to-date.`

Comment: Try the new `clj` command-line tool for a basic repl - see https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started for installation.

Comment: Although my question specifically addressed the issues surrounding running Clojure 1.9 on Windows, some of the information may be helpful to you - [see the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951107/213136)

Answer (score 6):

Clojure 1.9.0 is modularized with spec support broken off into two separate JARs that must be on your classpath.

See https://clojure.org/news/2017/12/08/clojure19

And as Alex Miller points out, the new [clj](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started) tool will take care of this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

These classes have been split out, you can download the missing jars here:

- [spec.alpha](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.clojure%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spec.alpha%22) - spec implementation
- [core.specs.alpha](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.clojure%20AND%20a:core.specs.alpha) - specifications for Clojure itself